# Defining recipient types (i.e. certifiedDeliveries) when sending an envelope from a template via API only

Tags: docusignapi

I am integrating Docusign into an application that requires new accounts to sign a contract. There are two signers - the account holder and us. When both sides have signed I would like the completed, signed document emailed as an attachment to our legal team.

Although 50-60% of signers will receive a default template, the remainder will be a custom document to be signed. As a result, I need all of the definitions to occur in my API call to Docusign so that I don't have to define the roles in Docusign for each custom document.

Currently the "Recipients and Routing" section of my Docusign template (within the Docusign interface) is empty.

Getting the first two signatures sequentially is working great. The problem is that last "person" should only receive a copy (since it is our legal@ email address). Docusign however is treating them as a signer even though there are no signature tabs defined.

Is there a way to get certified deliveries to work by defining everything in an API call? Or can I define it at the account level once in the Docusign interface so all completed agreements are always emailed to our legal team?

Details below:

[Here is the API call I am making](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Send%20an%20Envelope%20from%20a%20Template.htm)

I have a JSON array that looks like this (showing only the relevant portion - signHereTabs array intentionally left blank):

```
templateRoles[
    {
        "roleName": "Signer1",
        "name": "...",
        "email": "...",
        "routingOrder": "1",
        "signHereTabs": {

        }
    },
    {
        "roleName": "Signer1",
        "name": "...",
        "email": "...",
        "routingOrder": "2",
        "signHereTabs": {

        }
    },
    {
        "roleName": "Copy",
        "name": "...",
        "email": "legal@...",
        "routingOrder": "3"
    }
]
```

In the API documentation, it says templateRoles takes a Recipient type.
https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST API References/Recipient Parameter.htm

When I look at the examples, they start with an array key (i.e. certifiedDeliveries, Signers, etc). So I tried updating my templateRoles array with those keys gives me an INVALID_REQUEST_OBJECT error:

```
{"errorCode":"INVALID_REQUEST_BODY","message":"The request body is missing or improperly formatted. Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[API_REST.Models.v2.templateRole]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.\r\nTo fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.\r\nPath 'templateRoles.Signers', line 1, position 251."}
```

Here is what that API call looks like:

```
templateRoles[
    {
        "Signers": [
            {
                "roleName": "Signer1",
                "name": "...",
                "email": "...",
                "routingOrder": "1",
                "signHereTabs": {

                }
            },
            {
                "roleName": "Signer1",
                "name": "...",
                "email": "...",
                "routingOrder": "2",
                "signHereTabs": {

                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "certifiedDeliveries": [
            {
                "roleName": "Copy",
                "name": "...",
                "email": "legal@...",
                "routingOrder": "3"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Is there a different way to differentiate the recipient types in the templateRoles array? Or another way to get this end result?

Comment: When you are creating an envelope in DocuSign you either create one from a template or you create one out of a new document(s) where you upload your document bytes in the request.  If you are using a template then you can define whatever roles you would like through the Console, then assign your recipients to those roles through the JSON in your request.  However if you're not using a template, then you need to define everything about your recipients.  To add `certifiedRecipients` you should mimic the multipart/form-data call here:

Comment: https://10226ec94e53f4ca538f-0035e62ac0d194a46695a3b225d72cc8.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/rest-api-guide-v2.pdf#page=28